# Copy Data between AWS and IBM Machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, copy

I have an aws ec2 instance ( Ubuntu 14.04 )  and I have some data in it. 
Also I have IBM System X 3550 machine on which Ubuntu is installed. I want copy the data from AWS instance IBM. What way you recommend ?

Comment: So how can they connect each other, for example, with ssh and no firewall issue, then  you should be fine to `scp` the data between of them

Comment: they are in different networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use elastic ip of amazon machine and use scp.